# QMAKE multithreading flags

Tags: qt, qmake

**What flags should be set to build multithreading application?**

I see that there are `QMAKE_CFLAGS_THREAD` and `QMAKE_LFLAGS_THREAD`. I've found [this](http://ldc.usb.ve/docs/qt/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-cflags-thread) document, there are this flags described, but lacks information how to set them.

I've also found that I should add:

```
CONFIG += thread
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need:

```
CONFIG += thread
```

This will set up appropriate compiler and linker flags. The `_THREAD` variables allow you to modify those default flags in case they don't suit you.

However, you shouldn't actually need to even add `thread` to `CONFIG`. The default nowadays is to build with threading support anyway.

Comment: Ok. Could you also specify what can I modify with _THREAD variables? And how to set them. I saw in some example `-mthreads`. What are the posible values?

Comment: @krzych The possible values depend on your compiler, platform and thread library. Every compiler works different. Qt will use the correct flags for the platform you're using. If you want to modify them, then you can override the _THREAD variables. I don't see why you would want to.

Comment: I'm using mingw as gcc for windows targets. Thread library is QT

Comment: @krzych Qt is not a thread library. It depends on external support. Like pthreads on most Unix systems and Windows Threads on Windows. This is what is used under the hood when you use QThread.

Comment: So I'm on Windows as I said. The thread lib is Windows Threads.

Comment: @krzych Yes, it is. What is your question though?

Comment: The question is what values can I assign to `_THREAD` variables, and what this values stands for. Now when it's known what compiler and threads lib I'm using the answer should be possible?

Comment: @krzych I don't know. Read the documentation of GCC and MinGW to find out. What I do know is that qmake takes care of using the correct flags automatically without you doing anything.